# Spring/Kerberos - Clearing session cookies from PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, spring, apache, http, kerberos

I am having to integrate with a badly designed RPC API with Kerberos authentication.

To make matters worse it sets a session cookie and doesn't allow multiple requests asynchronously from the same client using the same cookie, so... I need to make sure each request has a cleared session cookie.

I'm using a custom HttpClient with a PoolingHttpConnectionManager and Resttemplate which doesn't allow me to clear the session cookie for me before it reuses a connection.

I need this cookie to be cleared before another request uses the same connection. How do I do this?

Comment: That's not a quick question.  :-)  Whoever designed this should have used the GSSAPI - standard Kerberos libraries right in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the server attaches a session ID but couldn't care less if it isn't there in subsequent requests. HttpClient allows you to disable cookie management and that seems to work.